# An action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ on complex $S^1$ and its geometric meaning

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

There is this question in my book and I'm not sure what the geometric meaning of this situation is.

Consider the unit circle in the complex plane 
$$S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}.$$
Let $n$ be a positive integer, consider the $n$-th root of unity
$$\xi=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\in\mathbb{C}$$
and let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ be the (additive) group of integers modulo $n$. Show that 
$$\phi_k(z):=\xi^kz$$
defines an action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ on $S^1$, explain its geometric meaning and show that $S^1/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$. What do you obtain when $n=2$?

So, a bunch of questions, but firstly I'm interested in the geometric meaning. What does this situation mean? With this knowledge I hope to be able to answer the other questions of the exercise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Look at were a few easy points go under the transformation when $k-1$ and $\xi$ is fixed.  Think about turning the circle.

Comment: Geometrically, you are rotating $S^1$ by $2\pi /n$ radians. The other geometric situation is that there is a projection $S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ with $z\mapsto z^n$ to winds the circle around $n$-times, and $\mathbb Z_n$ is the group of deck transformations of this. That $S^1/\mathbb Z_n$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ comes from this last observation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\xi = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, so, due to how nultiplication of complex numbers works, multiplication by $\xi$ is a counterclockwise rotation by that angle of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

You can express this in matrix form. Let $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb R^2$ as real vector spaces, and pick a basis $\{1, i\}$. Then, the operator of multiplication by $\xi$ looks like

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{2\pi}{n} & \sin\frac{2\pi}{n} 
\\ -\sin\frac{2\pi}{n} & \cos\frac{2\pi}{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

which is exactly the matrix of the plane rotation by the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.